# Merging two data frames in pandas that don't have the same column names and are different lengths

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames that I want to merge, problem is they are not the same length and don't have columns that overlap. I basically want to match the website with the company name, so they are all in one row. Some companies don't have websites, so I want these rows to just be populated with Naan.

Example of what I have:

| Company | other info 1 |
| --- | --- |
| name1 | balkdksj |
| name 2 | and so on |

| Website | other info 2 |
| --- | --- |
| http://www. some form of company name1 .com | bljadksjd |

Is there a was to merge them? The company name is not always the same as what is included in the web adress ( I tried stripping the company name of spaces and searching in webadress but they often don't align that way). Can you search for a specific word?

I want the table to look like:

| Company | other info 1 | Website | other info 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | njfhrif | name1 website | fjvbfjvb |
| name2 | bfjbfj | Naan | Naan |

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of `Company` names from `df1`, then use it to make a regex pattern for extracting from `Website` column of `df2`.  Get the result by left join using [`pd.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html), as follows:

(Assuming `df1` / `df2` are the names of your first and second dataframes)

```
pat = '|'.join(df1['Company'].values)

df_result = pd.merge(df1, df2, 
                     left_on='Company',
                     right_on=df2['Website'].str.extract(rf'({pat})')[0],
                     how='left')
```

If you want to match `Company` names with substring in `Website` only for *whole word match*, you can define the pattern `pat`, as follows:

```
pat = r'\b' + '|'.join(df1['Company'].values) + r'\b'
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_result)

  Company other info 1                                      Website other info 2
0   name1     balkdksj  http://www. some form of company name1 .com    bljadksjd
1  name 2    and so on                                          NaN          NaN
```

**Explanation:**

We generate the regex pattern `pat`, as follows:

```
print(pat)

'name1|name 2'
```

This regex pattern is feed into the [`str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to extract from column `Website` any matching company name in the column.  We then use it for matching with `Company` name from `df1` during merging.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help! This only seems to match one website :/ I think the problem is the full company name is not included in the website for example a company name could be : Adrian Lee & Partners and the website name is: http://www.aleepartners.com . Do you know if there is a way in regex to find words that have the most in common? Like to say is it any of the same words is would match

Comment: @IsabelJones In this case, it's difficult to do by merging as there is no common text to match.  Probably, you have to redesign the data structure of the second dataframe to include also the Company name, or some kind of company code (if company code, you need also to add company code in the first dataframe).  As URL can be quite different from the original name, your current data structure simply can't do this easily.